# ExcelPython return type mismatch issue

Tags: python, vba, excel

so I'm calling a python script from my Excel file with VBA and the ExcelPython reference.  The python script is working fine except for Excel keeps telling me I have a type mismatch on the noted line:

```
Function calcCapValue(times As Range, fRates As Range, strike As Range, vol As Range, delta As Double, pv As Range) As Variant

    Set methods = PyModule("PyFunctions", AddPath:=ThisWorkbook.Path)
    Set result = PyCall(methods, "CalculateCapValue", KwArgs:=PyDict("times", times.Value2, "fwdRates", fRates.Value2, "strike", strike.Cells(1, 1).Value2, "flatVol", vol.Cells(1, 1).Value2, "delta", delta, "pv", pv.Cells(1, 1).Value2))

    calcCapValue = PyVar(PyGetItem(result, "res"))   ' <--- TYPE MISMATCH HERE

    Exit Function

End Function
```

Can't figure out why, I'm following the example code from here: https://sourceforge.net/p/excelpython/wiki/Putting%20it%20all%20together/
and here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639887/Calling-Python-code-from-Excel-with-ExcelPython

Still getting this type mismatch and I can't figure out why.

Here's the python script:

```
#imports
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

#
#   Cap Price Calculation
#
def CalculateCapValue(times, fwdRates, strike, flatVol, delta, pv):

    capPrice = 0;


    #Iterate through each time for caplet price

    for i in range(0, len(times)):

        ifr = float(fwdRates[i][0])
        iti = float(times[i][0])

        d1 = (np.log(ifr/strike)+((flatVol**2)*iti)/2)/(flatVol*np.sqrt(iti))
        d2 = d1 - (flatVol*np.sqrt(iti))
        Nd1 = norm.cdf(d1)
        Nd2 = norm.cdf(d2)

        capPrice += pv*delta*(ifr*Nd1 - strike*Nd2)

    return {"res": capPrice}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't work with Python but either `PyVar` or `PyGetItem` is expecting an input of specific type and it is not getting that. And hence type mismatch error.

Comment: Interesting. Just before you return from the Python function, can you find out what `type(capPrice)` is? While I wouldn't say `PyVar` is expecting a *specific* type (after all, it's trying to create a VBA Variant), it may still be getting a type that VBA can't understand. The path of least resistance will be to do some additional processing on the Python side, just before the return, to transform the data into something that VBA *can* understand.

Answer (score 2):

Question answered on ExcelPython discussion forums on Sourceforge:

http://sourceforge.net/p/excelpython/discussion/general/thread/97f6c1b0/